# Laravel .env DB_HOST 127.0.0.1 vs localhost

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am confused about the `DB_HOST` variable in my Laravel environment file. Neither `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` appear to be working *completely*.

If the host is set to `127.0.0.1`, when I attempt to run a query within Laravel it returns the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = *email address* limit 1)

Whereas, if I use `localhost`, it connects fine.

However, when the `DB_HOST` variable is set to `localhost`, and I attempt to run  migrations or seeds, I am presented with the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = projectmanage and table_name
>      = migrations)

Whereas, if I use DB_HOST `127.0.0.1`, it migrates/seeds fine.

What is going on?

I am currently working with an installation of Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a database user that can sign in using localhost and not 127.0.0.1. Check the mysql.users table to verify. You can add an entry for 127.0.0.1 to connect with either.