# Why my laravel passport stopped working when migrated to vagrant from build-in server?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx, laravel-passport, vagrant-windows

So I had to implement facebook login, which requires https connection, before I was using php artisan serve, but it only allows http, now I decided to migrate whole project to vagrant. Everything works fine but passport.

I checked and found that theese two lines are causing internal error 500

```
auth()->attempt($loginData, true);

auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

when removed, I get no error. My whole login function look like this:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $loginData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

       $a = auth()->attempt($loginData, true);
        if(!$a) {
            return response(['message'=>'Invalid credentials', 'auth' => false]);
        }
        $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
        return response(['user' => auth()->user(), 'access_token' => $accessToken, 'auth' => true, "attempt" => $a, "auth()" => auth()]);
    }
```

In addition, I've created users via tinker, tokens and users were stored.

here is my db data

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name  | password                                                     | remember_token | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | admin | $2y$10$V8fM6Vvc7xOJxN/LPyImUeQNzG9/k3tSsaF8qf1NsxrzK9B3VPmsa | NULL           | 2019-08-26 15:22:02 | 2019-08-26 15:22:02 |
|  2 | demis | $2y$10$oRvcL0ZC2NQuGXE446GhfO1KBcAw3h8d/TGQmODL/AFHnat1I.Yvq | NULL           | 2019-08-26 15:45:27 | 2019-08-26 15:45:27 |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from oauth_access_tokens;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id                                                                               | user_id | client_id | name      | scopes | revoked | created_at          | updated_at          | expires_at          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2e82923d6fdc1cc98580b683952b7b96d555e67d6b7e06b8080f8a55227b6c1d7a755fc21b570941 |    NULL |         1 | authToken | []     |       0 | 2019-08-26 15:21:52 | 2019-08-26 15:21:52 | 2020-08-26 15:21:52 |
| 610f8fd1f2212ab257810de88605bff4e419f26477bcf63f8dfe20018d9bcf74797bb9c817d6450a |    NULL |         1 | authToken | []     |       0 | 2019-08-26 15:45:19 | 2019-08-26 15:45:19 | 2020-08-26 15:45:19 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What's wrong, Why I can't login, maybe there's something wrong with configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php artisan passport:install` on the new server.

Comment: I did it, same, now I think it's not working, because my ssl certificate is self-signed, and google throws error when using axios.

Comment: @LizardDerad by any chance, have you tried to use other SSL certificates? And by the way SSL certificates shouldn't affect axios.

Comment: Yes, I did, however issue is not about api request, but mysql connection. I don't know why, but laravel homestead wants `DB_HOST='localhost'` instead of `DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'` located in `.env` file. Also I don't know how I managed to create entries with tinker on `127.0.0.1` host and but not from webpage. First time using vagrant and it's confusing

Comment: One answer from another question says: _You probably have a database user that can sign in using localhost and not 127.0.0.1. Check the mysql.users table to verify. You can add an entry for 127.0.0.1 to connect with either._ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343409/laravel-env-db-host-127-0-0-1-vs-localhost @LizardDerad

Comment: Yes, that's the case