Vue + Laravel Passport auth not work after migrating server
I just migrate server, but the auth is not working.
Auth work in localhost and in postman, but not in application.
Error response is
{"errors":{"email":["Invalid email or password"]}}

I use Vue, Laravel 10, and Laravel Passport.
Error message is not from my controller. I use username instead of email in authentication. I don't know where is the error message from.
Thank you for help, sorry for my bad English.

verify your DB, table oauth_clients .

@Mate I move whole database. No change in database and secret key. How can I verify it? thanks

did you move private and public key to the new server ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663427/why-my-laravel-passport-stopped-working-when-migrated-to-vagrant-from-build-in-s
